# How to bring Gradient look - IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, gradient, xib

In my application I need to bring gradient look on my views, toolbars, UITableviewCells, etc.. I have done temporarily by setting background images, However I don't know it's a proper way, Is there any other way to do it?

Please have a look at these image

[image]

Comment: Go through CAGradientLayer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this to layer of your controls :

```
CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.frame = yourControl.layer.bounds;

gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.1f].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.4f alpha:0.5f].CGColor,
                        nil];

gradientLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                           nil];

gradientLayer.cornerRadius = yourControl.layer.cornerRadius;
[yourControl.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
```

**NOTE :** Here `yourControl` is your controls like View, buttons , imageview etc..

Hope it helps you.